# Table creation in MySQL results in a vague error

Tags: mysql, sql, string, create-table

I'm trying to create a table "Student" in MySQL,
However, I'm unable to debug the error.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
-> No INT NOT NULL,
-> Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
-> STIPEND DECIMAL(5,2),
-> STREAM VARCHAR,
-> AVGMARKS DECIMAL(3,1),
-> GRADE CHAR(1),
-> CLASS CHAR(3));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near AVGMARKS DECIMAL(3,1), GRADE CHAR(1), CLASS CHAR(3))' at line 5`
```

Any help would be appreciated.
I hope data types and column names are self-explanatory.
I've *wasted* 40mins of my life correcting this pathetic code

Answer (score 3):

A `varchar` column needs a length, as [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html):

> The `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store. For example, `CHAR(30)` can hold up to 30 characters.

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
    No INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    STIPEND DECIMAL(5,2),
    STREAM VARCHAR(10),     --> here
    AVGMARKS DECIMAL(3,1),
    GRADE CHAR(1),
    CLASS CHAR(3)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be in STREAM VARCHAR

You have to define the number of character in VARCHAR.
Try VARCHAR(100) to see if this works.